# Excel string parsing with random character

Tags: string, excel, parsing, text, formula

so, I have this string here `XX.XX.XX.XX.XX.XX`

I have to check if some of the XX matches a pattern. like `10.10.10.??.10.??`

why can't i use `EXACT(cell,"10.10.10."&??&".10."&??)`

I mean, how can I tell excel I need some of the number to match, but I don't care about others?

hope it's clear, I searched everywhere ._.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function that will accept wildcards (`EXACT` doesn't). Try using `COUNTIF`, e.g. with data in cell `A1` you can use this formula

`=COUNTIF(A1,"10.10.10.??.10.??")>0`

That will return `TRUE` if there's a match